# Is Galilean Conformal Algebra (GCA) isomorphic to any other algebra in $d$ dimension?

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra, spacetime-dimensions, galilean-relativity

I was recently studying stuffs related to Conformal Field theory and its Galilean version. It's known that CFT algebra in $d$ dimension is isomorphic to $SO(d+1,1)$ algebra. We also know that [Galilean Conformal Algebra](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=galilean+conformal+algebra) (GCA) in 2d is isomorphic to 2d Non-relativistic Conformal algebra. Is there any kind of isomorphism for GCA in general $d$ dimension like CFT?